# Bike with a SRAM XD(R) freehub body and trainer with a Shimano freehub body?

Tags: drivetrain, upgrades, trainer

I would like to change the wheelset of my bike, but I also have a smart trainer (Kickr core).

The wheelset I've retained so far are the Mavic Allroad, that are available with a Shimano or XDR freehub body. I understood that XDR free bodies are a longer version of the XD, so I could use a XD cassette with it — with a spacer.

My interest of using a XD cassette is to use a 10/52 cassette, instead of 11/51 that I could get from with a Shimano HG11 freehub body (no MicroSpline for the Mavic Allroad wheels yet).

But what about the trainer? To limit the cost and because I care less about the 10 tooth sprocket with the trainer, I was considering using a 11/51 shimano cassette on it with the same number of speeds. Would there be problems with the spacing/positionning of the cogs or with the derailleur?

Comment: Should be no problems. I’m assuming you’re referring to the 11-51 M5100 cassette?

Comment: Yes, for 11 speeds at least. For 12 speeds, there are other choices (Sunrace MZ800, Miche XM 12). I've also seen other possibilities with 11/50 cassettes (from Sunrace again).